# Wordpress multi loop and pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

Hi I'm currently working on this project

[bsearch](http://bsearch.underpk.com/it%E3%83%BB%E3%83%9E%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B1%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0/)

I want to create 2 style post one for the first 2 post and another style for the last 4 post.

Here is the code I'm using.

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'category' => 5 );
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

// content of the first 2 post here //

<?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata();?>

<?php
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'category' => 5,'offset' => 2 );
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

// content of the last 4 post here //

<?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

I searched and I knew that by this way the page pagination will not work.
But I only know a few basic in wordpress and php coding.

Can anyone help me solve this problem please?

Here is the design I made in [PSD](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ri4ugjrayktedm/nextPage%20genre.jpg?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'category' => 5 );
 $myposts = get_posts( $args );
$count = 1;
if($myposts->have_posts()): while($myposts->have_post): $myposts->the post();
       if($count < 3 ){
//content and style of the first two post 
$count++;
}
else{
//content and style of the rest of the post
$count++;
}
endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

This should do the trick.